# Tableau - have a chart with data which is not included in filter

Tags: tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

Using tableau cloud/desktop, how do you add a chart in a dashboard which has the opposite of your dashboard filters?

I am trying to get two charts on my dashboard: one showing the data filtered by my dashboard filters, and one with the opposite (the remaining data)

Comment: if you use parameters and sets controls to get your users choices, and then use boolean calculated fields that read those parameters and sets for your filters, then your solution is easy, just filter on calc-field on one viz, and 'not calc-field" on the other

Comment: works great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters and sets controls to get your users choices (instead of filters) and then create a boolean calculated field, say called [Show_Data?] that reads those parameters and tests those sets for your filter criteria.

Then your solution is easy, just filter on [Show_Data?] = TRUE on one viz, and [Show_Data?] = FALSE on the other.